# Clockpicker issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, cdn, clockpicker

Hello i used jquery clockpicker it's work fine but when i dynamic added some element and then re initialize clockpicker on that element it just blink and gone.

i made this function for initialize clockpicker

```
function initClockPicker() {
      $('.time').clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        default: "now",
        placement: 'bottom',
        align: 'left',
      });
}
initClockPicker();
```

and i also call this function after clone div which has input element with class 'time'

and i used clockpicker cdn => https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/jquery-clockpicker.min.js

Comment: Looks like a typo, maybe? ... remove the `,` after the `align: 'left'`. There is likely a related error in the browser console area.

Comment: no that doesn't effect anything.

Comment: Then please add whatever html (to the question) that is used with that code, to ease troubleshooting.